# pass same name as query string in URL and form. Which one will used by PHP?

Tags: php, html, query-string

pass same name as query string in URL and form. Which one will used by PHP?

For example,

```
<form method='post' action='test.php?nameval=abc'>
<input type='text' name='nameval'>
<input type='submit' value='Submit'>
</form>
```

Regards,
Jeyakumar N

Comment: Difference between `$_POST['nameval']` and `$_GET['nameval']` Try it yourself... Both can be used

Comment: why are you/would you be doing both?  perhaps we can suggest an alternative method

Comment: @Jeyakumar : please validate an answer

Answer (score 0):

You will catch the URL variable with `$_GET['numeral']`, and the form variable with `$_POST['numeral']` (Except if your form method is `GET`.)

Answer (score 0):

for `$_REQUEST` it depends on your `php.ini` how do variables get passed, [read here](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order), usually it's the `$_POST` that will pass, for the rest is the same:

```
$_GET['nameval'] = abc
$_POST['nameval'] = your input form
$_REQUEST['nameval'] = your input form
```